# How to add row with default values if not in consecutive order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this:

```
time  units   cost
0      4       10
1      2       10
3      4       20
4      1       20
5      3       10
6      1       20
9      2       10
```

As you can see, `df.time` is not consecutive. If there is a missing value, I want to add a new row, populating `df.time` with the consecutive time value, `df.units` with `2` and `df.cost` with `20`.
Expected output:

```
time  units   cost
0      4       10
1      2       10
2      2       20
3      4       20
4      1       20
5      3       10
6      1       20
7      2       20
8      2       20
9      2       10
```

How do I do this? I understand how to this by deconstructing all series into lists, looping through them and appending values when time is not equal to time - 1, but this seems inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `reindex` method with a call to `fillna` to do this:

```
# Build new index that ranges from time min to time max with a step of 1
new_index = range(df["time"].min(), df["time"].max() + 1)


out = (df.set_index("time")                # Index our dataframe with the original time column
         .reindex(new_index)               # Reindex our dataframe with the new_index, all empty cells appear as nan
         .fillna({"units": 2, "cost": 20}) # Fill in the nans for units and cost with 2 and 20 respectively
         .astype(int))                     # Due to NaNs that were in column from reindexing, we'll manually recast our
                                           #   data type from float to int (not necessary, but produces cleaner output)

print(out)
      units  cost
time             
0         4    10
1         2    10
2         2    20
3         4    20
4         1    20
5         3    10
6         1    20
7         2    20
8         2    20
9         2    10
```

Comment: `fillna` take dict forgot about it. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), then [`pd.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

```
idx = pd.RangeIndex(df['time'].min(), df['time'].max()+1) 
# If `df.time` is always sorted then,
# idx = pd.RangeIndex(df['time'].iat[0], df['time'].iat[-1]+1)

df = df.set_index('time')
df = df.reindex(idx)
df['units'] = df['units'].fillna(2).astype(int)
df['cost'] = df['cost'].fillna(20).astype(int)

# if you prefer not to hard-code the names of the columns, replace last
# the two lines with:
#   defaults = [2,20]
#   for (name, default) in zip(df.columns, defaults):
#       df[name] = df[name].fillna(default).astype(type(default))

      units  cost
time             
0         4    10
1         2    10
2         2    20
3         4    20
4         1    20
5         3    10
6         1    20
7         2    20
8         2    20
9         2    10
```

Comment: Going to edit this with a suggestion as a comment - feel free to edit further to either incorporate this into the actual code or to undo my edit, as you see fit...

Answer (score 0):

You can construct new DataFrame with complete "time" column and then do `.fillna()` from original dataframe (`df` is your original dataframe):

```
r = range(df['time'].min(), df['time'].max()+1)
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'time': r, 'units': [np.nan]*len(r), 'cost': [np.nan]*len(r)}).set_index('time')

df_out = df_out.fillna(df.set_index('time'))
df_out['units'] = df_out['units'].fillna(2).astype(int)
df_out['cost'] = df_out['cost'].fillna(20).astype(int)

print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
      units  cost
time             
0         4    10
1         2    10
2         2    20
3         4    20
4         1    20
5         3    10
6         1    20
7         2    20
8         2    20
9         2    10
```